# Не загружается весь контент сайта на странице

Tags: php

у меня такая проблема, у меня заказали сайт без адаптаций. Я его сделал при помощи php,css,html. Вот вроде заливаем уже всё на хостинг, проверяем личный кабинет, и бац! Не весь контент прогрузился, хотя на локальном сервере всё окей, на первом скрине показан результат который должен быть, на втором скрине показан результат который на сайте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В консоле есть какие нибудь ошибки?

Comment: Если в консоли нет ошибок - "включите" в php отображение ошибок

Comment: У вас не дорабатывают скрипты - нужно смотреть ошибки которые присылает сервер, по картинке у вас отключено отображение ошибок, данные не подгружаются из таблицы "расса" - возможно она не заполнена или не совпадают ключи. Необходимо в тестовом варианте включить отображение ошибок, проверить заполненность таблиц и соответствие ключей (попробовать другого героя, например, или провести новое заполнение свойств)

Comment: Есть две ошибки в консоли:

1. GET https://colorado-rp.com/?page=kabinet 500

2. colorado-rp.com/:1 GET https://colorado-rp.com/assets/css/grayscale.svg net::ERR_ABORTED 404

что они могут значить?

Comment: Первая - у вас ошибка в коде (больше всего) метода, который срабатывает, вторая - не находит ничего по ссылке